# Ansible ERROR! no action detected in task if I use full module name

Tags: ansible, yaml

I try to do a simple apt update on a remote system. My playbook looks like this

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: update
    ansible.builtin.apt:
      update_cache: yes
```

When I run it I get the error

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/opt/LabOS/ansible/test_pb.yml': line 6, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
  - name: update
    ^ here
```

However if I remove the module path (ansible.builtin.) it runs just fine. According to the documentation both notations should work. What am I missing here?

My ansible-playbook version is 2.7.7

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine => Ansible 2.7 ended its life on 18 june 2020, v2.8 on 21 january 2021 and v2.9 on 31 december 2021. Upgrade to 2.10 at the minimum which is anyway the first version to use Fully Qualified Collection Names (FQCN) as you tried above for your module name. Meanwhile, I suggest upgrading to the latest available version anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (optional) full name of the module like `ansible.builtin.apt` is only available starting from ansible version 2.10.

Since, you are on an older version, it gives an error and you can use only the short name of the module, for example: `apt`